# Issue running psycopg2 inside AWS Lambda Function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I'm getting the following error when trying to run psycopg2 in a AWS Lambda:

```
/var/task/functions/../vendored/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size: ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/functions/refresh_mv.py", line 64, in execute
session = SessionFactoryGraphQL.get_session(app=item['app'])
File "/var/task/lib/session_factory.py", line 22, in get_session
engine = create_engine(conn_string, poolclass=NullPool)
File "/var/task/functions/../vendored/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/task/functions/../vendored/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in create
dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
File "/var/task/functions/../vendored/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 554, in dbapi
import psycopg2
File "/var/task/functions/../vendored/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import ( # noqa
ImportError: /var/task/functions/../vendored/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size
```

The weird thing is: everything was working fine until yesterday (for more than 5 months), and suddenly stopped working. None of the libraries has been updated.

I tried to build from scratch, as in https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2, but still having the same error.

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the latest version of serverless framework. I assume that you are using serverless to deploy your lambda function.

`serverless remove`

`npm install serverless@1.20.2 -g`

This should work.